# How to organize leaderboard for react native quiz app?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I want to show a leaderboard for each quiz game I have on my quiz app. Any recommendations for how often I should be calling to update the top 5? There are 7 types of quizzes and I am also doing them by the region of the user. So, I have a collection for all users and a collection of each region's users in firebase. Each user has their own highscore for each of the 7 quiz games. I would have a leaderboard for all users and each region for each of the 7 quiz games. Sorry for this long message lol. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no singular correct answer here, as it all depends on your requirements (e.g. on data freshness) and limitations (e.g. on how much money you want to spend on updates).

Two common extremes are:

1. Update the leaderboard whenever a score is written.
2. Update the leaderboard periodically, like every night (when fewer peoples are playing)

There are many alternatives between these extremes, for example with a sliding window where you update every X hours, after Y games have been played, or a combination of those.